# Global variable is undefined when using it on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can use the global variable on other requests like `GET` but when I use it on `POST` it becomes undefined.

```js
var dirName;
app.post("/addFace", function (req, res) {
  //create directory
  const name = req.body.nameFace;
  dirName = "./public/labeled_images/" + name + "/";
```

Somewhere down the line:

```js
app.get("/addFace/upload", function (req, res) {
  res.render("upface");
  console.log(dirName);
});
```

which still works and console logs like intended and then:

```js
app.post("/addFace/upload", function (req, res) {
  console.log(dirName);
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, dirName);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      let fileName =
        file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, fileName);
    },
  });
```

Then it console-logged `undefined`.
TERMINAL::

Get -- ./public/labeled_images/bnmghjtyu/
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Running at localhost:3000
Post -- undefined

Comment: Are these 3 pieces of code all in the same file?

Comment: Why not send `nameFace` in the requests that would need to use it?

Comment: @hackape Yes they are at the same file

Comment: @PatrickEvans how?

Comment: The same way you send it when you make the post request to addFace, `app.post("/addFace"`

Comment: Another req.body.nameFace?

Comment: That would be how you receive it on the server side yes. You would need to send it like you do on the client side like you did when making the request to `/addFace`

Comment: I am not that skilled yet at coding.

github.com/Ma-cam2798/myFaceRecognition

Can you take a look at my repo and explain it further if it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

more than likely this is happening because the class/service containing dirName is getting recreated.

Comment: How should I fix it?

Comment: it seems like the easiest thing to do would be to include the value of "name" ( dirName = "./public/labeled_images/" + name + "/"; )  in the post to "/addFace/upload".

either way, there are architectural concerns if this code is used in a multi-tenant environment since its reliant on the user uploading a file immediately after adding a post request to "/addFace"

Comment: It results in name being undefined

Comment: @WilliamPoulson try to give a specific answer as a solution ... if you want to discuss the question use the comments section according to the question. :) great to have you on SO!!

Comment: https://github.com/Ma-cam2798/myFaceRecognition

You guys can check my git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

instead of getting the name from the req.body, I requested the name from the database that is appended when the folder is created.